# Solving system of inequalities where individual variables already have constraints

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, signal-processing

I'm currently trying to come up with an alternative to the Griffin Lim algorithm in signal processing, and I have come to a stage where I need to solve a system of inequalities where the variables are simple trigonometric functions. Here is a simple GNU Octave code which is self explanatory

```
s = [3 1 4 1 5 9 2 6];
f = fft(s);
a = abs(f);
an = arg(f);
p = an;
#vat1 is the value of the signal at time 1
vat1 = 0.25*(a(2)*cos(p(2)) + a(3)*cos(p(3)) + a(4)*cos(p(4))) + (1/8)*(a(1) + a(5)*cos(p(5)))
#vat2 is the value of the signal at time 2
vat2 = 0.25*(a(2)*(0.7071*cos(p(2)) - 0.7071*sin(p(2))) - a(3)*sin(p(3)) - a(4)*(0.7071*cos(p(4)) + 0.7071*sin(p(4)))) + 0.125*(a(1) - a(5)*cos(p(5)))
#vat3 is the value of the signal at time 3
vat3 = 0.25*(-a(2)*sin(p(2)) - a(3)*cos(p(3)) + a(4)*(sin(p(4)))) + 0.125*(a(1) + a(5)*cos(p(5)))
#vat4 is the value of the signal at time 4
vat4 = 0.25*(a(2)*(-0.7071*cos(p(2)) - 0.7071*sin(p(2))) + a(3)*sin(p(3)) + a(4)*(0.7071*cos(p(4)) - 0.7071*sin(p(4)))) + 0.125*(a(1) - a(5)*cos(p(5)))
#vat5 is the value of the signal at time 5
vat5 = 0.25*(a(2)*(-cos(p(2))) + a(3)*cos(p(3)) - a(4)*cos(p(4))) + (1/8)*(a(1) + a(5)*cos(p(5)))
#vat6 is the value of the signal at time 6
vat6 = 0.25*(a(2)*(-0.7071*cos(p(2)) + 0.7071*sin(p((2)))) + a(3)*(-sin(p(3))) + a(4)*(0.7071*cos(p(4)) + 0.7071*sin(p(4)))) + 0.125*(a(1) - a(5)*cos(p(5)))
#vat7 is the value of the signal at time 7
vat7 = 0.25*(a(2)*(sin(p(2))) + a(3)*(-cos(p(3))) + a(4)*(-sin(p(4)))) + 0.125*(a(1) + a(5)*cos(p(5)))
#vat 8 is the value of the signal at time 8
vat8 = 0.25*(a(2)*(0.7071*cos(p(2)) + 0.7071*sin(p(2))) + a(3)*(sin(p(3))) + a(4)*(-0.7071*cos(p(4)) + 0.7071*sin(p(4)))) + 0.125*(a(1) - a(5)*cos(p(5)))
```

I'm using a user defined signal 's'(just for an example, I am using the first few digits of Pi). It can be replaced with any 8 point signal. Next, I have the variables f(discrete fourier transform of signal), a(magnitudes of each of the components of f), and an(angle of each of the components of f).

Now that I have all of this, I have written expressions for the value of the signal at time ranging from 1 to 8. This is given by vat1, vat2.... vat8.

I know that the "vat" variables have a minimum possible value of 0 and a maximum possible value of 9.
That is,

```
0<=vat_x<=9
```

Given this set of 8 inequalities, my intention is to solve for the possible values of phase p from only values of amplitudes a. It obviously won't give the exact phase values, but any sensible possible range is great.

I could assume that cos(p) itself is a variable, but then it gives really weird answers. Is there any way of solving this set taking into consideration that the variables involved have predefined limits?